# How to reuse a type generated from a property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, types

I'd like to be able to reuse the type of a property that was generated from a user perspective.

```
type Properties = {
  state: Record<string, unknown>;
}

function utility<T>(state: T): T {
  return state;
}

function Component(props: Properties): JSX.Element {
  const objState = utility<typeof props.state>(props.state);

  return <div />
}

type State = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}

const state: State = {
  prop1: 'anything',
  prop2: 10,
}

<Component state={state} />
```

The basic type of `state` in `Properties` is `Record<string, unknown>` since the type is still unknown but should respect a "shape" with string keys and values of any/unknown type.

I'd like to be passing to any other function using `state`, its actual type `State` and not the basic type `Record<string, unknown>`, which would result in `objState` to be of type `State`.

The solution presented here does not seems to work but shows what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not sure if this goes in contradiction with types at compile time. Let me know if this is impossible or otherwise what would be the closest solution.

Comment: Maybe you just want `Component` to be *generic* in the type of `props`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nll9xN), but the example doesn't motivate it.  It's unobservable from outside (you get a `JSX.Element` no matter what the input is) and you are just assigning to `objState` on the inside without using it.  Could you [edit] with a [mre] that motivates what you're doing?  Then, if the generic suggestion meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining. And if not, then hopefully your edit will show what's wrong with doing that.

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thanks for the time you took to answer. The example was left as minimal as possible because it doesn't affect what is following. I've chosen another solution, which use a factory function instead, this way I can reuse the type without any difficulty. Your answer is valid, it does work as intended, if you wish to write an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Do you want to write up your own answer with the factory function suggestion?  I'm not likely to write up an answer here unless the code gets edited to motivate the answer, such as showing any code where it matters that `objState`'s type is narrower than just `Record<string, unknown>`.  If you're willing to do that, great.  If not, I'll just disengage. Good luck either way!